# How to force refresh client js from server side?

Tags: javascript, browser

Here is the case:

I get a js to monitor web ads.Because of the browser cache,when i update js on server side,js on client side will not be refreshed immediately.How could i force refresh client js as soon as i update js on server side?

p.s. Add version number strategy is not useful in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTTP's [cache-control mechanisms](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.1.3) to control the browser's caching.

When serving a copy of your JS file, include an [ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) and/or [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header in the response.  Also include a "[Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9): must-revalidate" header.  This tells the browser that it must check back with the server every time, and it can send an [If-None-Match](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) and/or [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) header in future requests to ask the server to send the file only if it's changed.

If you'd like to avoid the load of browsers checking with the server every time, and it's OK for the changes to not take effect immediately, you can also include a [Date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) header with the current time and an [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header set to some point in the future — maybe 12 or 24 hours.  That allows the browser to use its cached copy for the specified amount of time before it has to check back with your server again.

HTTP's cache-control features are pretty robust, but there are plenty of nuances, such as controls for intermediate caches (e.g. other systems *between* your server and the user's browser).  You'll want to read about [caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13) overall, not just the specific header fields that I've mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

Simple strategy - add a version number as a query string to your js files, and change the number. This will cause the browsers to fetch your js files again -

```
<script src="mysource.js?version=123"></script>
```

Whenever you change your script on the server, change this version number in the html too. Or better yet, apply a random number as the `version` value every time you request this script.

Comment: This strategy can not be used in my case.My js is used by different projects,on this strategy means once i update my js,a bunch of guys have to update their codes,it costs too much.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Allerson: Probably no. The other guys using your script can append a random number as a version value. In this way, every time the script is requested, it will be requested with a new value (the chances of generating a random number twice is quite low, if the number is really huge). So they won't have to do anything manually. This is how some JavaScript frameworks (i.e., Sencha Touch) loads their JS components.

Comment: A new problem:cause we append a random number as a version value,it means js can not be cached,our server will receive more requests.this js will be requested 20 million plus times one day and we just have 3 servers.In this way,pressure gonna be huge.

Comment: Excellent hack, it saved my day  - Thanks :)

Comment: This does not work if browser decides to cache index.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by changing the name of the file. Add some version number (could be like parameter, i.e. `filename.js?v=time();` for PHP for example) or just append some random numbers at the end of the filename.

Actually I'm not sure whether you can force the client to refresh this type of files. But when changing the file name you will force the browser to get the newest version.